# Retrieving outlook Contacts via python win32com

Tags: python, windows, outlook, win32com

I am Trying to get Contacts out of `Outlook` using `Python`.
The code is :

```
import win32com.client
import pywintypes

o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = o.GetNamespace("MAPI")
profile = ns.Folders.Item("Outlook")
contacts = profile.Folders.Item("Contacts")
```

but its giving error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_pro.py", line 7, in <module>
    profile = ns.Folders.Item("Outlook")
  File "C:\DOCUME~1\Manoj\LOCALS~1\Temp\gen_py\2.7\00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-00000
0000046x0x9x3\_Folders.py", line 70, in Item
    ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(81, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Of
fice Outlook', u'The operation failed. An object could not be found.', None, 0,
-2147221233), None)
```

I don't understand why it's throwing the error, as I do have a profile named `Outlook`

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't have a profile named "Outlook" (Unless you created one)

Usually the "Profile Name" is the name given to the top level folder, that your "Inbox" is in. As in "Personal Folders"

Answer (score 2):

- This option works for extracting contacts when Outlook is connected to an Exchange server.
- I managed to find/modify a working solution. It saves the email addresses and the full names of all your contacts in Outlook as a list:

```py
import win32com.client

# Outlook stuff
outApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
outGAL = outApp.Session.GetGlobalAddressList()
entries = outGAL.AddressEntries

# Empty list to store contact info
data_set = list()

# Iterates through your contact book and extracts/appends them to a list
for entry in entries:
    if entry.Type == "EX":
        user = entry.GetExchangeUser()
        if user is not None:
            if len(user.FirstName) > 0 and len(user.LastName) > 0:
                row = list()
                row.append(user.FirstName)
                row.append(user.LastName)
                row.append(user.PrimarySmtpAddress)
                """print("First Name: " + user.FirstName)
                print("Last Name: " + user.LastName)
                print("Email: " + user.PrimarySmtpAddress)"""
                data_set.append(row)

# Prints list
print(data_set)
```

Original code:
https://www.excelcise.org/getting-information-from-outlook-global-address-list-gal-with-python/

Answer (score 1):

- This option works for extracting contacts from the `Outlook.pst` file, not an Exchange server.

  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800926/7758804) for extracting contacts from the Global Address List on an Exchange server.
- This requires Outlook installed on Windows, but not running.

  - Tested with python 3.8, Windows 10, Outlook Office 365
- Once the `contacts_items` object is created, use the appropriate `Property` to extract the desired information.

  - Available [`Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem#properties) for [`ContactItem object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem)
- I have noticed that `outlook.Application.Quit()` isn't closing Outlook, so it may need to be closed in Task Manager.

```py
import win32com.client

# create outlook object
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# create an object for the contacts in the default folder
contacts_items = ns.GetDefaultFolder(10).Items

# print name and email address
for c in contacts_items:
    print(f'{c.FullName}: {c.Email1Address}')

# create a dict of contacts
contacts = {c.FullName: c.Email1Address for c in contacts_items}

# close the application
outlook.Application.Quit()
```

---

- The following code is from [Import outlook contacts using win32com](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/173216-import-outlook-contacts-using-win32com/), but has been updated for python 3.8

### `MSOutlook Class`

```py
import win32com.client


DEBUG = 0

class MSOutlook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outlookFound = 0
        try:
            self.oOutlookApp = \
                win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
            self.outlookFound = 1
        except:
            print("MSOutlook: unable to load Outlook")
        
        self.records = []


    def loadContacts(self, keys=None):
        if not self.outlookFound:
            return

        # this should use more try/except blocks or nested blocks
        onMAPI = self.oOutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        ofContacts = \
            onMAPI.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderContacts)

        if DEBUG:
            print(f"number of contacts: {len(ofContacts.Items)}")

        for oc in range(len(ofContacts.Items)):
            contact = ofContacts.Items.Item(oc + 1)
            if contact.Class == win32com.client.constants.olContact:
                if keys is None:
                    # if we were't give a set of keys to use
                    # then build up a list of keys that we will be
                    # able to process
                    # I didn't include fields of type time, though
                    # those could probably be interpreted
                    keys = []
                    for key in contact._prop_map_get_:
                        if isinstance(getattr(contact, key), (int, str, unicode)):
                            keys.append(key)
                    if DEBUG:
                        keys.sort()
                        print("Fields\n======================================")
                        for key in keys:
                            print(key)
                record = {}
                for key in keys:
                    record[key] = getattr(contact, key)
                if DEBUG:
                    print(oc, record['FullName'])
                self.records.append(record)
```

### Class Usage

```py
if DEBUG:
    print("attempting to load Outlook")
oOutlook = MSOutlook()
# delayed check for Outlook on win32 box
if not oOutlook.outlookFound:
    print("Outlook not found")
    sys.exit(1)

fields = ['FullName',
            'CompanyName', 
            'MailingAddressStreet',
            'MailingAddressCity', 
            'MailingAddressState', 
            'MailingAddressPostalCode',
            'HomeTelephoneNumber', 
            'BusinessTelephoneNumber', 
            'MobileTelephoneNumber',
            'Email1Address',
            'Body'
            ]

if DEBUG:
#     import time
    print("loading records...")
    startTime = time.time()
# you can either get all of the data fields
# or just a specific set of fields which is much faster
#oOutlook.loadContacts()
oOutlook.loadContacts(fields)
if DEBUG:
    print(f"loading took {time.time() - startTime} seconds")

print(f"Number of contacts: {len(oOutlook.records)}")
    
for i in range(len(oOutlook.records)):
    print(f"Contact: {oOutlook.records[i]['FullName']}")
    print(f"Body:\n{oOutlook.records[i]['Body']}")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use python 3.9 and above and you are only interested in email addresses the following is enough.

```py
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
addresses = outlook.Session.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries

mails = [
    user.PrimarySmtpAddress for x in addresses
    if (user := x.GetExchangeUser()) is not None
]

print(mails)
```