# How to properly initialize win32com.client.constants?

Tags: python, outlook, constants, win32com, office-automation

I'm writing a simple email filter to work upon Outlook incoming messages on Windows 10, and seek to code it up in Python using the `win32com` library, under Anaconda. I also seek to avoid using magic numbers for the "Inbox" as I see in other examples, and would rather use constants that *should* be defined under `win32com.client.constants`. But I'm running into simple errors that are surprising:

So, I concocted the following simple code, loosely based upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800130/257924 :

```py
import sys
import win32com.client

try:
    outlookApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
except:
    print("ERROR: Unable to load Outlook")
    sys.exit(1)

outlook = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
ofContacts = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderContacts)
print("ofContacts", type(ofContacts))
sys.exit(0)
```

Running that under an Anaconda-based installer (Anaconda3 2022.10 (Python 3.9.13 64-bit)) on Windows 10 errors out with:

```
(base) c:\Temp>python testing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Temp\testing.py", line 11, in <module>
    ofContacts = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(win32com.client.constants.olFolderContacts)
  File "C:\Users\brentg\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 231, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(a)
AttributeError: olFolderContacts
```

Further debugging indicates that the `__dicts__` property is referenced by the `__init__.py` in the error message above. See excerpt of that class below.  For some reason, that `__dicts__` is an empty list:

```py
class Constants:
    """A container for generated COM constants."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dicts__ = []  # A list of dictionaries

    def __getattr__(self, a):
        for d in self.__dicts__:
            if a in d:
                return d[a]
        raise AttributeError(a)


# And create an instance.
constants = Constants()
```

What is required to have `win32com` properly initialize that `constants` object?

The timestamps on the **init**.py file show 10/10/2021 in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is to change:

```
outlookApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

to

```
outlookApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
```

The longer answer is that `win32com` can work with COM interfaces in one of two ways: `late-` and `early-binding`.

With `late-binding`, your code knows nothing about the Dispatch interface ie. doesn't know which methods, properties or constants are available. When you call a method on the Dispatch interface, `win32com` doesn't know if that method exists or any parameters: it just sends what it is given and hopes for the best!

With `early-binding`, your code relies on previously-captured information about the Dispatch interface, taken from its Type Library. This information is used to create local Python wrappers for the interface which know all the methods and their parameters. At the same time it populates the Constants dictionary with any constants/enums contained in the Type Library.

`win32com` has a catch-all `win32com.client.Dispatch()` function which will try to use early-binding if the local wrapper files are present, otherwise will fall back to using late-binding. My problem with the package is that the caller doesn't always know what they are getting, as in the OP's case.

*The alternative `win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch()` function enforces early-binding and ensures any constants are available*. If the local wrapper files are not available, they will be created (you might find them under %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\gen_py\xx\CLSID where xx is the Python version number, and CLSID is the GUID for the Type Library). Once these wrappers are created once then the generic `win32com.client.Dispatch()` will use these files.